# Are some software programs "illegal" in Germany?

Tags: law, software, germany

A German [article](http://www.pcwelt.de/galerien/illegalsten-Hacker-Tools-338102.html?bild=1) in PC Welt (PC World) claims to list a number of "illegal hacker tools".

The list includes:

- Network Sniffers

  - [Aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)
- Copy-Protection Circumvention Tools

  - [AnyDVD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvd.html), [DVD Shrink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_Shrink), [Vista Loader](http://www.mydigitallife.info/vista-loader-213-windows-vista-activator-2008-support-sp1-with-no-boot-string-free-download/)
- Password Recovery Tools

  - [Cain & Abel](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html), [ElcomSoft Distributed Password Recovery](http://www.elcomsoft.com/edpr.html), [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/), [Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/), [Passware Kit Enterprise](http://www.lostpassword.com/kit-enterprise.htm), [Protected Storage PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/pspv.html), [Pst Password](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/pst_password.html)
- Keyloggers

  - [Perfect Keylogger](http://www.blazingtools.com/bpk.html), Shark
- Worms

  - Internet Worm Maker Thing

Are these programs, themselves, illegal in Germany?

In my understanding, just the *use* of a program, that may be an illegal action, but that the software itself is not illegal.

Comment: And it goes on... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_number

Comment: As far as I know, you can't export software from the US, for example, to countries which it has an embargo on. Also, some cryptography software (not cryptography keys, the software used to manipulate them) can be treated as weapons when it comes to exporting.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). When I search for the term "illegal programs", I find this question as the number 1 result. Please link to someone making a claim that "illegal programs" exist, so we can assess their claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking The link in the OP is to a `.de` site; and cracker tools may be illegal in Germany: http://arstechnica.com/security/2007/05/germany-adopts-anti-hacker-law-critics-say-it-breeds-insecurity/

Comment: I don't read German, but the fact that the list is in German doesn't mean that it applies only to Germany, just as list in English don't apply only to English speaking countries, unless the list specifically claims that those programs are illegal in Germany, I think that the question should remain with a global perspective.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed That would be a separate question. If people believe that this list of programs is illegal in Germany, then that is a notable claim that we can examine.

Comment: @Articuno, the fact that the list appears in a German site, doesn't mean that it's localized to Germany, or German speaking countries. If the list doesn't specify that it applies only to Germany, than it can be assumed that a (German) reader of the list will also not a assume that the list is localized to Germany.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed The test is whether many people believe that this list is illegal in Germany. The claim is not that the list is illegal *only* in Germany, but that the list is illegal *at least* in Germany. Whether it is localized to Germany doesn't change the fact that people believe this list to be illegal in Germany.

Comment: For the newcomers: This question was initially broad and vague. While it was put on hold quickly, it still managed to garner many speculative answers before then. The original claim source was provided, and it turned out to be a German magazine. The question was largely rewritten to match the source, which leaves some of the early answers looking off-topic.

Comment: @Ilya: I understand that it is possible for the German author to intend the claim to be broader (not least, the whole EU), but I am concerned about making it global for two reasons: (1) an answer that demonstrates the software itself is perfectly legal in the USA would be addressing a strawman if it was illegal in Germany, and (2) giving a universal answer would be close to impossible, requiring a thorough understanding of all jurisdictions. If we can find that the original author did intend it it to be a global claim, however...

Comment: @IlyaMelamed was right. I'm not from Germany, I'm from Switzerland and I was curious about the law overall. I didn't know, that there were huge differences in countries (except africa/asia). What Ilya says here, was totally my question (maybe it was because of my not-so-good english). :) I wanted to know, if programs, that can do good AND bad things, could be illegal and compared it to a car. A car is to 99.9% a useful "tool", while you could also drive into someone and kill him/her (with intention). WillThe application hurtThe law, or is itTotally the users action, that will bring punishment.

Comment: @TrudleR, does the provided link claim that the software are illegal in Germany (or Switzerland) only, or does it restrict its claims to any specific jurisdiction?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed: No, it doesn't. It justs says "illegal Software" and nothing else. :)

Comment: Vagueness is sometimes INTENTIONALLY used in german law, exactly to allow the benefit of the doubt to a benevolent user while allowing to throw the book at malevolent users. Eg from an official comment on weapons law: "Dementsprechend wurde das Führensverbot auch nicht mit einem Straftatbestand, sondern mit einem Bußgeldtatbestand in § 53 Abs. 1 Nr. 21a WaffG bewehrt, so dass die Polizei nach dem Opportunitätsprinzip nur in angebrachten Fällen einzuschreiten braucht.  Hierbei steht der Polizei ein Beurteilungsspielraum zu...."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there is a Law, 202c StGB, which prohibits several things in relation to computer programs:

http://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/202c.html

> (1) Wer eine Straftat nach § 202a oder § 202b vorbereitet, indem er
>         1.      (...)
>     2.  Computerprogramme, deren Zweck die Begehung einer solchen Tat ist,
>
> herstellt, sich oder einem anderen verschafft, verkauft, einem anderen
>   überlässt, verbreitet oder sonst zugänglich macht, wird mit
>   Freiheitsstrafe bis zu einem Jahr oder mit Geldstrafe bestraft.

That means: Who prepares a law violation as in § 202a and b, which is spying on data and catching foreign data by producing, organizing, selling, renting or spreading a program or giving access to such a program can be punished with jail or a monetary penalty.

In former times, only the concrete action was prohibited (202 a and b). In the discussion of the law in the parlament, which I followed in full length and discussed at multiple occasions, many experts argued that the possible victims of such programs need access to them to defend themselves. That the tool in itself isn't evil, only some uses.

The parties which argued for the law didn't solve the conflict, that they wanted to restrict production and spreading of such tools in general for prophylactic reasons and the idea only to ban bad usage.

The problem has now to be solved in court. The judges can refer in their decision not only to the text of the law, but to the protocols of the debate in the parlament to make a decision in the spirit of the law. AFAIK, the law is in force for about 5 years now, but got recently fresh attention by a commercially available hacking tool and the house search by police of many people, who ordered that tool.

But there is not a definitive list of software which is affected by the law. The court has to rule in each single case.

Comment: This is the closest answer to my original question (and also to the one written above). Thank you.
So if there is an application with good purposes, but which you can abuse, there is no concrete law (at least in Germany). :)

Comment: "Which of these is not like the others?" Wireshark. Maybe they should instead to the sane thing and require all network adapters sold in Germany to not support promiscuous mode instead.

Answer (score 17):

Computer Games are programs and there are many computer games banned in various countries around the world due to their content, which are summarized in a [Wikipedia  article on the issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_banned_video_games).

Specifically in Germany, some games can be prohibited for dissemination, but are still legal for

> [p]rivate possession (and thus playing it) and acquisition (such as downloading a demo from the Internet)

The possible reasons for banning a game are violence or  dissemination of Nazi symbols in any way:

> § 86a outlaws the use of symbols of unconstitutional organizations, § 130 Volksverhetzung (agitation of the people), and § 131 instructions for crimes. In the official lists, these three sections are always bundled, so any action game that contains swastika flags and/or any depiction of Adolf Hitler) is listed alongside racist propaganda pieces.
>
> § 131 outlaws representation of violence in media "which describe cruel or otherwise inhuman acts of violence against human beings in a manner which expresses a glorification or rendering harmless of such acts of violence or which represents the cruel or inhuman aspects of the event in a manner which injures human dignity."[25]
>
> § 130 and § 131 make it to a criminal offense to do following with corresponding scriptures:
>
> - distributing / selling
> - issuing in public, demonstrating or otherwise making available
> - leaving it to a person under the age of 18
> - producing, buying, delivering, storing, offering, announcing, praising, importing or exporting to use them within the meaning of the letters 1 to 3.
>
> This means, that the import or purchase and the possession for personal use are still legal for persons over 18 years.

A list of all currently banned games, and games on which the ban has expired (the ban is for 10 years) appears in the wiki article.

It should be noted that the list is relatively short, because game publishers publish edited or cut versions of their games in Germany in order to comply with local laws:

The game [Return to Castle Wolfenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Castle_Wolfenstein) was edited to not mention the Nazis directly by name or symbol:

> In the German version of the game, it avoids making direct reference to Nazi Party and the "Third Reich", in order to comply with strict laws in Germany. The player is not battling Nazis but a secret sect called the "Wolves" led by Heinrich Höller, whose name is a pun of the original character Himmler (Himmler roughly translates as "Heavener", Höller as "Heller"). The Nazi swastika is also not present, the German forces use a Wolfenstein logo which is a combination of a stylized double-headed eagle prominent in most Nazi symbolism, a "W" (standing for Wolfenstein), and the Quake III: Team Arena "QIII" logo (the game engine and network code that RTCW is based upon).

And the games in the [Grand Theft Auto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_%28series%29) series were edited to be less violent. From the [GTA Wikia](http://gta.wikia.com/Germany):

> Since Germany is quite strict on ratings, after paranoia over violent video games, a number of the GTA games (since GTA III) have suffered cuts or edits. Some examples include: the removal of blood, pedestrians no longer dropping money when killed, no headshots, some missions removed, some weapons missing, or lack additional functionality.

Most countries that ban games, ban them because of depictions of violence. Some countries also ban games because of other content, like South Korea, which bans games that have content which reflects on North Korea to:

> avoid increasing diplomatic tensions

other reasons include nudity and sexuality, offensive to the culture, nationality or religion of the country and other various reasons.

Comment: Your answer touches only the scope of games, which were not even mentioned in the question.

Comment: @userunknown, computer games are a subset of computer programs, they are not the software mentioned in the list itself but are "some software" as the question asks. This is obviously only a partial answer that doesn't touch on the main issue of the question, but it's still an answer to the question which adds information which is (in my view) relevant.

Comment: *agitation of the people* (in your Wikipedia quote) is a bad, watered-down translation of *Volksverhetzung*. The [article on that specific word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksverhetzung) translates it as **incitement of hatred against a segment of the population**, which is much more accurate.

Comment: @codesparkle, add this information through an edit.

Comment: Computer games aren't "illegal hacker tools". Either the edit of the question was wrong, than it needs to be rolled back, or the answer is off topic.

Comment: @userunknown: Comparing the edit-history of the question with this answer, the editing was wrong and too assuming. This answer totally fits the old version of the question.

Comment: @phresnel: If you look at the comments below the question and the accepted answer, you'll find that that is not really the case. The question was from the beginning about software, which you can use to do unlawful things, not such software, where every usage is considered against the law.

Comment: @userunknown: Ah, yes. Exactly this kind of confusion is why a question, once asked, should IMHO not change the semantics anymore.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, programs can be illegal in many jurisdictions. For example distribution or sale, and in some jurisdictions even possession, of tools (be it physical or software), which *exclusive* use is hacking is illegal in most countries.

For example *18 U.S. Code § 1029 - Fraud and related activity in connection with access devices*:

> (9) knowingly uses, produces, traffics in, **has control or custody of,
>   or possesses hardware or software**, knowing it has been configured to
>   insert or modify telecommunication identifying information associated
>   with or contained in a telecommunications instrument so that such
>   instrument may be used to obtain telecommunications service without
>   authorization; or

Comment: Although, exceptions are made, of course, for people with legitimate business use. It's like carrying a prybar or a set of lockpicks. It's reason enough for the police to bring you in, but they still need to prove intent.

Comment: @SeanDuggan IANAL, but according to above wouldn't even mere possession be a crime?

Comment: Further down in the code, http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1029, they list exceptions, including use to prevent hacking.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I'm referring to the part *"but they still need to prove intent"*. If mere possession is a crime, they don't. Also if I'm reading that correctly, the exception you mention apply only to law enforcement agencies.

Comment: g.2:
In a prosecution for a violation of subsection (a)(9), (other than a violation consisting of producing or trafficking) it is an affirmative defense (which the defendant must establish by a preponderance of the evidence) that the conduct charged was engaged in for research or development in connection with a lawful purpose.

Comment: So, true, by default, it's assumed that you must be up to no good, but a valid defense is to be able to prove that you were doing research. G.1 has specific exceptions for people working for said telecommunication companies. So, basically, it's a lot like lockpicks where they can bring you in for possession, but you can prove reasonable use.

Comment: @SeanDuggan fair enough. Although it's more like *"they still need to prove intent"* applies to the defendants, who'd need to prove that exception applies to them, rather than the prosecution having to prove that they had malicious intent.

Comment: What about tools, that can do big damage in hands of "false guys", but that could also help other people? For example aircrack: Maybe you forgot your own password and want to hack your own router? The tool will be used the other way in 95% I think, but there are still others, that use it for good. Aircrack is outdated by the way, it's just an example. :)
Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: This doesn't address the question in its current form, which asks about Germany.

Comment: @Flimzy: but it wasn't about Germany, and I don't feel like rewriting the answer.

Comment: @vartec: I can understand... although I would suggest deleting the answer then, if you don't feel like editing it to make it relevant.

Comment: @Flimzy: The question was never about Germany. My original question was edited by a guy who didn't unterstand me. I can't see a single sentence that I wrote, someone completely edited it in the order he understood it.

Comment: @Flimzy: it become about Germany after edit vandalism, so **I don't feel like deleting valid answer to the question as asked by OP** either.

Comment: @TrudleR: Then you should revert the invalid edit.